# contol on textbox and focus on textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, focus

I have 2 textbox : textbox1 and textbox2.
i have to compare textbox1.text with an integer.

If textbox1.text >20 and textbox1.text<30 then 
focus on the next textbox
Can anybody help me PLzzzz.

```
 Private Sub textbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim int As Integer
    TextBox1.MaxLength = 2
    Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, int)

    If (int > 20 Or int < 30) Then
        ' next textbox
    Else
        TextBox1.Focus()
        MsgBox(“enter an integer btw 10 et 20”)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly what your problem is because you haven't really stated what's going wrong, but one thing I immediately notice is you're checking if a number is within a range with "OR". Now, just look at how you stated in your question "If textbox1.text >20 AND textbox1.text<30 then focus". Now why is your code using "Or" when you need "And"?

Comment: Also if you change the OR to AND, you also need to move the `TextBox1.Focus()` to inside the IF statement.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm understanding this correctly, you're trying to check to ensure `textbox1` is bigger than 20, but less than 30; if so, focus on `textbox2`.

I'm unable to test the following code right now, I'll check back later and correct it if need be.

```
Private Sub textbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
TextBox1.MaxLength = 2

    If Val(TextBox1.Text) > 20 and Val(TextBox1.Text) < 30 Then
          TextBox2.Focus()
    Else
          TextBox1.Focus()
          MsgBox(“enter an integer btw 10 et 20”)
     End If
End Sub
```